# How can I combine the following code?

Tags: php

I want to display 3 `ul`s:

```
$one = '<ul>';
$j = 0;
while($j<3){
  $one .= '<li data-src="' . $myarray[0][$j] . '"></li>';
  $j++;
}
echo $one;
echo '</ul>';

$two = '<ul>';
$j = 0;
while($j<3){
  $two .= '<li data-src="' . $myarray[1][$j] . '"></li>';
  $j++;
}
echo $two;
echo '</ul>';

$whatever = '<ul>';
$j = 0;
while($j<3){
  $whatever .= '<li data-src="' . $myarray[2][$j] . '"></li>';
  $j++;
}
echo $whatever;
echo '</ul>';
```

How can I combine the above in shorter way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    echo '<ul>';
    for ($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++) {
        echo '<li data-src="' . $myarray[$i][$j] . '"></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: Thanx. I was struggling a lot. I was trying to use for loop with multiple variables so was not working. Your solution worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what you want to display first. Here you will have 3 lists, each of your 3 list containing a single sub-list. So you need to loop through your $myarray (which is a 2D array) :

```
    <?php $j = 0; ?>
    <?php foreach( $myarray as $row ): ?>
    <ul>
        <li data-src="<?php echo $row[$j] ?>"></li>
    </ul>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

`foreach` will go through your first dimension, so you only deal with the next dimension, which make you `$row` becoming a one-dimension array instead of 2 which is lighter to deal with.

This solution is templating-oriented, which suit well when you need to separate your logic from your graphic.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = "";  
   for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++) {
       $html .= '<ul>';
       $j = 0;
       while($j<3){
          $html .= '<li data-src="' . $myarray[$i][$j] . '"></li>';
          $j++;
       }
       $html .= '</ul>';
    }
    echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this springs to mind:

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;

while($i < 3) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ($j < 3) {
        echo '<li data-src="' . $myarray[$i][$j] . '"></li>';
        $j++;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    $i++;
    $j = 0;
}
```

Since you have two loops (which you could also replace with for-loops), you can nest them to only type your html once.
This way you also don't need to store the html in strings. You can echo them right away.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have the same code repeating three times. You can simply replace it with a nested for / while loop:

```
$i= 0;
while ($i < 3) {
    echo '<ul>';
    $j = 0;
    while ($j < 3) {
        echo '<li data-src="' . $myarray[$i][$j] . '"></li>';
        $j++;
    }
    echo '</ul>';
    $i++;
}
```